# Next js build failed because of webpack error

Tags: npm, next.js

For some reason npm fails to create a build of next.js app when I run `npm run build`. It crashes when it tries to get `logo.png` which is originally located in `public` directory where I serve all static assets like images and icons. I don't really understand what happens and why I get this error : \

```
    info  - Linting and checking validity of types
    info  - Creating an optimized production build
    Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: File C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\.next\static\media\logo.ecfa485c.PNG does not exist.
    at makeWebpackError (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:308185)
    at C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:105236
    at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:28771), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:68649
    at C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:414:143
-- inner error --
Error: File C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\.next\static\media\logo.ecfa485c.PNG does not exist.
    at Job.emitDependency (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:39473)
    at async Promise.all (index 5)
    at async Object.nodeFileTrace (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:35430)
    at async C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:135:28
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async TraceEntryPointsPlugin.createTraceAssets (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:89:9)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: File C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\.next\static\media\logo.ecfa485c.PNG does not exist.
    at Job.emitDependency (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:39473)
    at async Promise.all (index 5)
    at async Object.nodeFileTrace (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:35430)
    at async C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:135:28
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async TraceEntryPointsPlugin.createTraceAssets (C:\Users\Daniil\MY_PROJECT_DIR\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:89:9)


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

my project structure looks like this

```
C:.
├───.next
│   ├───cache
│   │   ├───eslint
│   │   ├───swc
│   │   │   └───plugins
│   │   │       └───v4
│   │   └───webpack
│   │       ├───client-development
│   │       ├───server-development
│   │       └───server-production
│   └───server
├───components
├───node_modules
├───pages
│   ├───catalog
│   │   └───product
│   └───news
├───public
│   ├───about_us
│   ├───catalog
│   ├───contacts
│   ├───footer
│   ├───gallery
│   ├───our_works
│   ├───reviews
│   └───why_we
└───styles
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Change the file ending from `PNG` to `png`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but this wasn't the case : )
I posted solution below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was with the way I imported images. For some reason I did it like this:

```
import logo from '@/public/logo.PNG'

...

<img src={logo.src} />
```

But the right way is to directly point path to image in `img` element:

```
<img src='/logo.PNG' />
```